# How to decipher my mounted HDD fielsystem?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am on Ubuntu 18.04. My HDD filesystem

```
root@miki:/media/miki# ll
total 578576
drwxr-x---+  4 root root      4096 нов 20 06:49 ./
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root      4096 феб 28  2019 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 miki miki 592415426 нов  5 17:53 66341bf4-bb30-4834-a87f-a7ea6b75e09
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root      4096 авг 28 18:44 66341bf4-bb30-4834-a87f-a7ea6b75e09a/
drwxr-xr-x  18 miki miki      4096 феб 26  2019 main/
```

What is the difference between the `66341bf4-bb30-4834-a87f-a7ea6b75e09` `and 66341bf4-bb30-4834-a87f-a7ea6b75e09/`?

Comment: The latter is actually `66341bf4-bb30-4834-a87f-a7ea6b75e09a/` which makes it distinct. So the only remaining difference is that the former is a file and the latter is a directory..

Comment: it is actually unclear what you are asking about